# Creating a Graph with Python in Jupyter Notebook Using Altair and I Cannot Move the legend for the Color

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, altair

```
bars = alt.Chart(marvel).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('OpeningWeekendNorthAmerica', axis=alt.Axis(title='Gross Revenue Opening Weekend')),
    y=alt.Y('Title', axis=alt.Axis(title='Movie Title')),
    color="Budget"
)

text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode(
    text='Distributor'
)



(bars + text).properties(height=900)
```

I Just want to know how to move the color key from the upper right to the middle right side of the graph to avoid the text overlapping.
[Link to Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pToRU.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `orient` and `offset` legend properties to control the location of the legend (see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Legend.html)

For example, here is a legend located at the bottom left:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

alt.Chart(data.cars()).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color=alt.Color('Origin', legend=alt.Legend(orient='bottom-left'))
)
```

[image]

For even more control, you can set `orient='none'` and use the `legendX` and `legendY` configurations to specify the position relative to the top left corner of the chart:

```python
alt.Chart(data.cars()).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color=alt.Color('Origin', legend=alt.Legend(orient='none', legendX=410, legendY=110))
)
```

[image]